# Disable parent window controls when there is an error in userControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

In a Windows form I've some controls and a UserControl. I've a ErrorProvider in the UserControl. I want to stop editing all the controls in the Form if there is an error in the userControl. Is there any way to do that?

I am using errorProvider.BindToCustomDataAndErrors(..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any built-in way in `Windows Forms` that I'm aware of, to do something like that. I do believe you should implement it by yourself.

You can create an event like `ErrorRecieved` (say), and Disable controls in its handler.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095427/disable-whole-form-by-error-provider) also a link to similar SO question.